# Saving a file on Android, but not to the SD Card

Tags: android, sd-card

If an SD card is not present in an Android device then where do we store the recorded file?

Answer (score 0):

simply in phone memory you can store files

Answer (score 0):

You can create files that are private to your application by using [Context.openFileOutput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).